# magento hide product form main page

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

In my Main Website, I create 2 Store name **ram** and **shyam** store and every store have 2-2 view.
I upload product in **ram** store and **shyam** store.
Now when I go to ram store view home page display all product list (also Shyam store).
Also when I go to Shyam store page display all product (also ram store).

Question:- how to disable display product of another store view. means I want to display only a particular store view product on a particular store home page.

Comment: What is the code you have written to show homepage products?

Comment: Please add store wise condition into your homepage product collection.

Comment: you can check with your admin panel, magento have this features.